# JSON mapper for Nested objects and arrays

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a Json String from a webservice response.

This JSON sting has nested objects and arrays. I have tried to map it with java objects using jackson and GSON but i am getting errors in both the cases.

This is my Json:

```
{"events": [{
    "Code": "4", 
    "eventDataSet": {
        "Bar":{"EvDesc":"WRAP_UP"},
        "Foo":{
            "AcssId":"**1234",
            "EvCSId":"12‌​34",
            "custId":"3501234","Recid":"bknz"
        }
    }
]}
```

I want to pull the values of Bar and Foo objects from this json.

Please suggest how can i map such type of responses.

Comment: {
    "events": [
        {
            "Code": "4",
            "eventDataSet": "{\"Bar\":{\"EvDesc\":\"WRAP_UP\"},\"Foo\":{\"AcssId\":\"**1234\",\"EvCSId\":\"1234\",\"custId\":\"3501234\",\"Recid\":\"bknz\"}"
        }
    ]
}             i want to pull the values of Bar and Foo objects from this json.

Comment: Copy json and question from comment, format json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries such as `Gson` and `Jackson` shouldn't have any trouble de-serializing valid `JSON` Strings.

Most probably the problem is with object types you're using to de-serialize your inputs.

You can use [this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate POJO from one of your `JSON` responses. Input your JSON and select `JSON` as Source Type.

Then, with `Gson`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Person p = gson.fromJson(inputString, Example.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amila. Below is the Json String i am using.                             
{
    "events": [
        {
            "Code": "4",
            "eventDataSet": "{\"Bar\":{\"EvDesc\":\"WRAP_UP\"},\"Foo\":{\"AccessId\":\"**1234\",\"EvHubCSId\":\"1234\",\"custId\":\"3501234\",\"Recid\":\"bknz\"}"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Your json seems to have some problem. Here is modified json, and I am able to convert it to Object using jackson.

```
{
    "events": [{
        "code": "4",
        "eventDataSet": {
            "bar": {
                "evDesc": "WRAP_UP"
            },
            "foo": {
                "acssId": "**1234",
                "evCSId": "12??34",
                "custId": "3501234",
                "recid": "bknz"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```